# gulp-livereload with vagrant environment : livereload.js not accessible

Tags: javascript, vagrant, puphpet, gulp-livereload

I have a problem using `gulp-livereload` in my vagrant environment (generated with puphpet).
My computer is a Windows Host, and the VM a Debian.

I use this gulpfile :

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    less       = require('gulp-less')
    lr         = require('tiny-lr'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    server     = lr()
;

gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src('assets/less/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
        .pipe(livereload(server))
    ;
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/less/*.less', ['less']);
    livereload.listen(35729, function(err){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'less']);
```

And when Chrome Extension add the magic JS file I obtain this message :

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT http://markup.dev:35729/livereload.js?ext=Chrome&extver=0.0.5

But in my VM, if I run the following command line, I get it

```
wget http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?ext=Chrome&extver=0.0.5
```

Comment: Do you know that 'lr', 'livereload' and 'server' variables in your code are globals?

Comment: Yes I know but I don't think that it's the problem

Comment: Yeah... although using globals is bad and unpredictable, I agree. That's why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: Where is it getting `markup.dev` from?

Comment: markup.dev is define in my host file, and hosted by the VM

Answer (score 8):

I don't have enough information to be certain, but I would guess that your problem is you are trying to access the page from the host, but the livereload port isn't forwarded (the VM has it's own IP address and vagrant can be configured to forward certain ports to the host so that they "appear" to be local on the host).

Try adding the following line to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 35729, host: 35729
```

(For documentation see: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html)

Alternatively if you are directly hitting the VM (that is you have `markup.dev` mapped to the guest's IP) it may be worth verifying that there is not a firewall configured on your VM which might block the livereload port from external access.

Comment: Hi, 

markup.dev is defined in my host file, and hosted by the VM. 
When I open http://markup.dev in my browser, it's working, without specific configution for the port 80

I tryed your solution but that don't fix my problem :(

Comment: Did you reload your vagrant configuration after adding the line above? Because this really sounds like a networking issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the port forwarding worked automagically. However, I had to specify the VM's IP as host:

```
livereload.listen({
    host: '192.168.33.10'
});
```

**Update**: Passing `null` works, too:

```
livereload.listen({
    host: null
});
```

I guess that the underlying [http server](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) behaves differently when passing `'localhost'` [explicitly](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload/blob/develop/index.js#L8).